# Sql Server In-memory table implemented with Redis

Tags: sql-server, performance, caching, redis, in-memory

Starting from Sql Server 2014 Microsoft implemented In-Memory OLTP that IMO is very interesting feature!
I never tried it but I'm interested in because it can really speed up my "READ" actions (I mean select queries).

My idea is to run "WRITE" actions (insert, update, delete) directly to the disk (not in memory) to be sure that data are written persistently.
Instead "READ" actions (in particular queries on big tables, counters at Application_Startup, ecc) will be done in memory.

Now I have some questions: 
1) is in-memory table synchronized in some way with the data saved in disk?

2) Is possibile to implement what I wrote above or I misunderstood?

3) Because the enterprise version of Sql Server 2016 costs too much for a startup or a small company, is possible to implement all of this using Redis? 
   I'm new also on Redis and I'm not sure that it has a "in-memory" table feature.
   Searching on Google I found that it made a cache (it's not clear of what, queries?) and it's an in-memory data structure store (key-value pairs)

Thank you in advance guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first and second question:

In-Memory in SQL Server 2016 can be created in two ways, one is with Schema Only - Which means data is volatile and it stays only in-memory

```
CREATE TABLE TestInMem (
i int,...<columns>
)
WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON,
          DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY);
```

Other way is Schema and Data - Here both will be persisted into secondary storage on periodic basis and your operation will be faster because you will be directly hitting primary memory for accessing data.

```
CREATE TABLE TestInMem (
i int,...<columns>
)WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON,
          DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx

Comment: Ok, so for example: consider the a table where I save "POST" objects... In the second way "SCHEMA_AND_DATA" I'm able to decide that all "write" actions must be done directly to disk and all "read" actions must be done on memory?

Comment: There are other DMV's to track that.. We can check sys.dm_xtp_system_memory_consumers etc., but not sure whether i understood your problem correctly..

Comment: My question is: when I insert a new row to the table (created with "DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA"), the data is wrote in memory and then synchronized with physical storage or it's added directly to the disk and then Sql Server synchronize it with memory?
Just to understand how it works

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the third question:

You can't directly impose sql queries in redis. Redis doesn't work that way. Instead it has structures like set, sorted set, hash maps, you can use them and try to achieve equivalent queries but definitely not the easy way though and will never achieve everything sql offers. For example complex joins, group by, order by might need more than 5 or 6 operations with redis, provided you store them perfectly and choose the optimal way to retrieve.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that... because it's a noSql... I read something about Redis and it doesn't work like sql server in-memory... I searched on Google some examples about how implement counters (e.g. User counter, Post counter, ecc) in Redis integrating it with my web api \ sql server data but I didn't find nothing helpful... is it a complex work or it can be achieved quickly? I have to decide which is the best technology to use to implement realtime counters and to make my queries faster and it's not a simple decision

Comment: redis works well for incrementer kind of things.To put it simple, if you have a table less than or equal to 2 columns implementing them in redis is pretty simple, when the columns goes beyond 2 it becomes complex for storing as well as mainpulating complex queries.